# THREE.JS GLTFLoader Error loading GLB: RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 81717

Tags: three.js

I'm getting this error on mobile:

```
Error loading GLB: RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 81717
at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
at eval (GLTFLoader.js:1307:20)
```

My loader:

```
this.gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
this.gltfLoader.setMeshoptDecoder(MeshoptDecoder);
this.gltfLoader.load(url, function(gltf) {
    if (gltf) {
        callback(gltf);
    } else {
        callback(null);
    }
}, undefined, function(error) {
    console.error('Error loading GLB:', error);
    callback(null);
});
```

The error appears to happen here:

```
class GLTFMeshoptCompression {
    constructor( parser ) {
        this.name = EXTENSIONS.EXT_MESHOPT_COMPRESSION;
        this.parser = parser;
    }
    loadBufferView( index ) {
        const json = this.parser.json;
        const bufferView = json.bufferViews[ index ];
        if ( bufferView.extensions && bufferView.extensions[ this.name ] ) {
            const extensionDef = bufferView.extensions[ this.name ];
            const buffer = this.parser.getDependency( 'buffer', extensionDef.buffer );
            const decoder = this.parser.options.meshoptDecoder;
            if ( ! decoder || ! decoder.supported ) {
                if ( json.extensionsRequired && json.extensionsRequired.indexOf( this.name ) >= 0 ) {
                    throw new Error( 'THREE.GLTFLoader: setMeshoptDecoder must be called before loading compressed files' );
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return buffer.then( function ( res ) {
                const byteOffset = extensionDef.byteOffset || 0;
                const byteLength = extensionDef.byteLength || 0;
                const count = extensionDef.count;
                const stride = extensionDef.byteStride;

                const source = new Uint8Array( res, byteOffset, byteLength ); // <--- here
```

Model: Blender Gltf export compressed with gltfpack:

```
./gltfpack -cc -sa -mm -kn -i test.glb -o test2.glb
```

Render info:

```
memory: geometries: 40, textures: 17
programs: 17
render: frame: 4338, calls: 62, triangles: 31324, points: 0, lines: 0
```

gltfpack 0.19

three r148

Phone: Samsung Galaxy A32 / google chrome

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: You can find the reason on the MDN web docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError - This is exactly what you expect if too much data is trying to be crammed in. I'm not sure threejs or the browsers will solve this issue for you, I think you will have to somehow reduce the amount of data you load in?